# Trying to find the missing dates between the range of dates

Tags: python-3.x

I have a weekly date as a range and I want to calculate missing dates between that period. The date range is starting from 1992, so can't put it manually. The date data is available in excel in the below format.

1992-12-18

1992-12-25

1993-01-08

when I run the below code by putting the first two date as start and end, I got the correct result.

I have tried to convert this date as pd.to_datetime(dates[0]).dt.date
also pd.to_datetime(dates[0]).dt.normalize()

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("-------------------",header=None)
for t in data[0]:
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(t), %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(t+1), %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    date = (start + datetime.timedelta(days = x) for x in range(0,(end- 
start).days))
for data_ob in date:
    print(data_ob.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

ValueError: cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] (aka without the excel file dependency)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to get all the missing dates between two ranges of dates using `datetime` and `calendar` modules, without returning duplicate dates and also without returning any date found in the input date's list:

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange
from pprint import pprint


def get_missing_dates(dates: list) -> list:
    """Find missing dates"""
    out = set()
    for date in dates:
        _date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        year, month, day = _date.year, _date.month, _date.day
        for missing in range(*monthrange(year, month)):
            to_add = datetime(year, month, missing).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            if date not in out and not day == missing and to_add not in dates:
                out.add(to_add)
    return sorted(list(out))


dates = ['1992-12-18', '1992-12-25']
missing_dates = get_missing_dates(dates)
pprint(missing_dates)
```

output:

```
['1992-12-01',
 '1992-12-02',
 '1992-12-03',
 '1992-12-04',
 '1992-12-05',
 '1992-12-06',
 '1992-12-07',
 '1992-12-08',
 '1992-12-09',
 '1992-12-10',
 '1992-12-11',
 '1992-12-12',
 '1992-12-13',
 '1992-12-14',
 '1992-12-15',
 '1992-12-16',
 '1992-12-17',
 '1992-12-19',
 '1992-12-20',
 '1992-12-21',
 '1992-12-22',
 '1992-12-23',
 '1992-12-24',
 '1992-12-26',
 '1992-12-27',
 '1992-12-28',
 '1992-12-29',
 '1992-12-30']
```

Comment: How can I put dates from excel to dates as there is a format issue i.e. Timestamp('1992-12-29' 00:00:00)